# Android Read a Text file Exactly

Tags: java, android, file-io

I have a text file that has been signed and I need to read this file into a string exactly as it is. The code I am currently using:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        invitationText.append(line);
        invitationText.append('\n');
    }
    invitationText.deleteCharAt(invitationText.length()-1);
```

Works if the file has no return at the end, but if it did have a return then the signature check would fail. There's a lot of questions around this so I'm having a hard time finding one that specifically answer this, so this may be a duplicate question. Some restrictions I have though are:

- It can't use the methods added in Java 7 (I'm on android, I don't have access)
- It can't use the org.apache IOUtils method (I can't bring in that library)

Whether it loops or reads the whole thing in one go doesn't matter to me I just need 100% guarantee that regardless of carriage returns in the file, the file will get read in *exactly* as it is on disk.

Comment: "that regardless of carriage returns in the file, the file will get read in exactly as it is on disk" -- if it is has to be exactly as it is on disk, read in the `byte[]` using an `InputStream`, validate your signature, and *then* worry about creating a `String` from it.

Comment: The signature is part of the original string, I can read it in as both but ultimately I need to get the file as a string in order to verify it because that's just how the library works. I agree, a byte array makes more sense, but at this point we are working with strings for everything. Could I read the whole file in as a byte array and convert that byte array to a string without loss?

Comment: "The signature is part of the original string, I can read it in as both but ultimately I need to get the file as a string in order to verify it because that's just how the library works." -- then look at the source of the library, see how they write the file with the embedded signature out, and do the inverse to read it in. This is why signatures are frequently stored separately from the things that they are signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I use:

```
 public static String readResponseFromFile() throws IOException {
    File path = "some_path";
    File file = new File(path, "/" + "some.file");
    path.mkdirs();
    String response = null;

    if (file != null) {
        InputStream os = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            os.read(bytes);
            response = new String(bytes);
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            throw ioEx;
        } finally {
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```